# how to call layout from UI component button?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to jump from one **UI_COMPONENT** to another **UI_COMPONENT** through layout file and hopefully passing URL in button

This is my UI_COMPONENT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="duplicate" >
            <url path ="duplicate/index/index"/>
                <label >duplicate </label>
            </button>

        </buttons>
    </settings>
</form>
```

and want to call my layout but it gives me 404 error 
this is my layout file name "**duplicate_index_index**"

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="duplicate_detail"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: is your controller present?

Comment: check your directories you must have placed files in wrong directory.

Comment: i forgot to put my routes files in to proper directory ... etc/adminhtml/routes.xml